# Print sorted data under a heading in python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x

I want to sort data in a txt file that has the following format:

```
name      number1 number2  number3 number4

nick      3       2        66      40  
Anna      3       1        33      19   
kathrine  4       4        100     258
```

based on **fourth column (number3)** but it doesn't seem to work when number3 is three digits number.

The program simply asks three times for a name. Each name enters numbers other than 0
and prints the name, how many numbers given (number1), how many of them are greater than 10 (number2),  percentage of them (number 3) and the sum of all numbers given(number4).

I would like also to print data aligned under each heading.The headings doesn't need to be stored
in the file.

The code is the following

```
def how_to_sort_a_file():

from operator import itemgetter    

with open('myfile2.txt') as f:
    lines = [line.split(' ') for line in f]

output = open('myfile2(sorted).txt', 'w')

for line in sorted(lines,key=itemgetter(3), reverse=True):
    output.write(' '.join(line))

output.close() 

print('')
with open('myfile2(sorted).txt') as f:

##prints an empty line between lines
    for line in f:
        print(line)
##end function
##################################################################

##################
## main program ##
##################

file=open('myfile2.txt', 'w')
file.close()

for i in range(3):
    name=input('insert your name: ')
    number=int(input('insert number, 0 to terminate: '))
    given_numbers=0
    numbers_greater_10=0
    Sum=0
    while number!=0:
        Sum=Sum+number
        given_numbers=given_numbers+1
        if number>10:
            numbers_greater_10=numbers_greater_10+1
        number=int(input('insert number, 0 to terminate: ')) 

    percentage=int((numbers_greater_10)*100/given_numbers)   

    with open('myfile2.txt', 'a') as saveFile:        
          saveFile.write(name +' '+str(given_numbers)+' '+str(numbers_greater_10)+' '+ str(percentage)+' '+ str(Sum)+"\n")

    how_to_sort_a_file()
```

I'm totally inexperienced with Python and i would appreciate any help.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide us with `myfile2.txt` so we can better test your code.

Comment: how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing this using Python's library [pandas](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas):

Read the text file into a dataframe like below:

```
In [1397]: df = pd.read_fwf('myfile2.txt')

In [1398]: df
Out[1398]: 
       name  number1  number2  number3  number4
0      nick        3        2       66       40
1      Anna        3        1       33       19
2  kathrine        4        4      100      258
```

Now, you can simple sort on the column `number3` in an ascending order:

```
In [1401]: df = df.sort_values('number3')

In [1402]: df
Out[1402]: 
       name  number1  number2  number3  number4
1      Anna        3        1       33       19
0      nick        3        2       66       40
2  kathrine        4        4      100      258
```

You can see above that the rows are sorted by `number3`. Now, simply write this to a text file:

```
In [1403]: df.to_csv('my_output.txt', index=False)

mayankp@mayank:~/Desktop$ cat my_output.txt 
name,number1,number2,number3,number4
Anna,3,1,33,19
nick,3,2,66,40
kathrine,4,4,100,258
```

The good part about this is that you don't have to write complex code for parsing the file.

Comment: I wrote the following statement before doing anything else  import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Comment: You need to install pandas. `pip install pandas`

Comment: thanks for your advise. I really don't know how to do that but i'll try to find out. Any simpler solution, based on the approach that i followed in my code would be very helpful at this point.

Comment: Actually, using pandas is very simple in this case. Just google how to install pandas.

Comment: @angvla Were you able to do it?